# How to compare 2 files and returning matching values with awk

Tags: file, awk, merge

I have 2 files :

File1:

```
DS496218    
DS496219
```

File2:

```
DS496218    40654      
DS496218    42783     
DS4962187   40654   
DS4962186   45454
DS49621228  42783
```

output_file

```
DS496218    40654     
DS496218    42783
```

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A {print $0}' File1 File2 > output_file
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your command looks fine to me, what you are getting in your output file?

Comment: It creates an empty file, but im sure that there are matching records

Comment: Check with `cat -v file1` and `cat -v file2` once if you see control M characters in it?

Comment: No M character. The 2 columns in file2 are separated by a TAB delimiter.

Comment: Ok try like: `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next} ($1 in A)' File1 FS="\t" File2 > output_file` once if this helps you?

Comment: Still an empty file.

Comment: @Marco the code you have is correct to do what you say you want to do with the sample input files you provided whether the separator is a tab or blanks or both. Copy/paste those files from your question and run the code in your question and it will produce the output in your question. So, if that's not working for your real files then there's something about your real files that's different from the example you posted. Since we can't see your real files you'll have to look into that further yourself.